# Remove/Update Excel Add-In Sideloaded via Shared Catalog

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing/testing an Excel Add-In. I added it to the desktop version using the "shared folder catalog" process outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

I updated the manifest XML for new ribbon commands, but Excel is not updating. I am unable to update/remove/reinstall an add-in installed from the "Shared Folder". I tried removing the add-in catalog and re-adding it in Trust Center Settings, but that did not work.

Answer (score 5):

It is caching your manifest. Try bumping the version number in the manifest. This will alter Excel that it's cached manifest is no longer valid.

If bumping the version doesn't trigger the update, you can manually clear your cache by deleting the contents of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\`. For non-Windows environments, see [Testing & Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting#changes-to-add-in-commands-including-ribbon-buttons-and-menu-items-do-not-take-effect) in the Office.js documentation.

Comment: That didn't work. You're right about caching. I tried removing/re-adding the manifest file and the ribbon commands, but the original add-in version persists.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this was pressing the `Refresh` button in the top-right corner of the 'Office Add-Ins' dialog.

Comment: Ugh.  Awful UX.  To be clear:  Remove the application from the catalog first, then go to add-ins and click 'refresh'.

Comment: @Mr.B, i'm having the same problem. Could you elaborate more on your comment ? I'm not having any luck with getting my side loaded add-in to update on my Windows machine. I've tried Refreshing the add-in, removing it and re adding it, updating the version number and deleting the Wef file mentioned below. I'm sure i'm missing a simple step somewhere, unfortunately I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below by @marc-lafleur hints in the right direction: it is about caching. But it is not the `Wef` folder you have to empty, it's the `Temporary Internet Files` as Office actually uses IE to display the JS add ins and such everything is loaded from the IE's cache.
For dev, it might be best to just disable it.